# Laravel validation: validate field only if another is present

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I wanted to validate an 'account_id' only if 'needs_login' is present. I did this:

```
$rules = [
    'account_id' => ['required_with:needs_login','custom_validation']
];
```

But it doesn't work, because if needs_login field is not present but account_id has some value, then it tries to do the 'custom_validation'.
I also tried to put the 'sometimes' parameter

```
$rules = [
    'account_id' => ['required_with:needs_login', 'sometimes', 'custom_validation']
];
```

but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

> **P.S.:** Remember that I wanted to validate the account_id only if needs_login is present, not to check if account_id is present if needs_login does.

Comment: Which Laravel version are you using, 5.1?

Comment: The version is 4.2.17

Comment: Maybe it can't be done like this, because I want a validation that if it's true, then validate the other validations also, and if it's false then stop the validation controls and let it pass. But if you have any ideas it'll be appreciated

Comment: Illegal Pigeons answer is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this works for Laravel 5 if you are going the 'sometimes' route. Perhaps you can adapt for L4? Looks like it's the same [in the Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#custom-validation-rules).

```
$validation = Validator::make($formData, [
    'some_form_item' => 'rule_1|rule_2'
]
$validation->sometimes('account_id', 'required', function($input){
    return $input->needs_login == true;
});
```

Answer (score 12):

Have you tried required_if?

```
$rules = [
    'account_id' => ['required_if:needs_login,1']
];
```

Comment: Is the same as before. If the account_id is present, even if the needs_login isn't, then it tries to do the other validations for the account_id

Comment: What other validations is it trying to do? "account_id" is only required if "needs_login" has a value. If "needs_login" does not have a value, then the validation will fail. I don't see how it's doing another validation?

Comment: This is the right answer. However, I don't think the ```[``` ```]``` array tags should be there.

Comment: @zeros-and-ones Yes, you are correct about the array tags. When I use array tags (for testing what would happen), I get an 'Array to string conversion' error message in my debugger.

IllegalPigeon - I can confirm your solution works for me, minus the array tags.